# Selenium not finding radiobutton

Tags: c#, selenium

I cannot get selenium to recognize a radiobutton, I have written code that I believe should find the element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
        <input id="ctl00_contentMain_PartyType_0" type="radio" value="Party" name="ctl00$contentMain$PartyType"></input>
```

Selenium C#

```
        //Selecting Party radio button
        var partyRadioBtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name = 'ct100$contentMain$PartyType']"));
        partyRadioBtn.Click();
```

Comment: what's happening instead?  is partyRadioBtn set to null?

Comment: the result is telling me that it cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

Aren't "name" attribute dinamic? Looks like it is.
Should definetely work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#ctl00_contentMain_PartyType_0")).Click();
```

Comment: This still gives me a "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: Can you provide more html? Could it be inside an iframe?

Comment: There is some more html, I am almost positive that it's not in an iframe

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I can handle this radio button properly with the input @value tag like this:

```
        //Selecting Party radio button
        var partyRadioBtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value = 'Party']"));
        partyRadioBtn.Click();
```

Comment: that means you have dynamic id and/or names. Selenium is not magic, it just does what you will say.

Comment: I do have to disagree, sometimes selenium is magic. It was just a matter of finding what element to find.